# How to get string values from web services and make into spinner selected item?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am working on a project where user will fill his details through a profile activity, including the user needs to tell what sports(Rugby, Basketball, etc..) he is favorite with and what level(beginner, intermediate, expert) he is good in that sport. He can enter multiple games from the selected event.

After he entered all the details he is allowed to go into the next activity. If he likes to edit his profile, there is an edit option in the app. After clicking the edit button all the details became as the text from web server string and I'm unable to make the spinner selected item to list below as selected item.

I have given the code below for how I'm getting the spinner selected item :

```
spinobj = new dyspin();
spinobj.setGames(nameone);
spinobj.setLevels(levelone);
gamelist.add(spinobj);
games = new Gson().toJson(gamelist);
```

its pojo class:

```
public class dyspin {

    private String games;

    private String levels;

    public String getGames() {
        return games;
    }

    public void setGames(String games) {
        this.games = games;
    }

    public String getLevels() {
        return levels;
    }

    public void setLevels(String levels) {
        this.levels = levels;
    }
}
```

any help will be appreciated!!!